# Does it make a difference in LSTM as to how I give the input?

Tags: keras, lstm

So, as we know the input of the LSTM is always is a 3D array: `batch_size, time_steps, seq_len`. So, does it make a difference if I give input of the LSTM as: `batch_size, 1, time_steps * seq_len`?

So for example, I have 5 features and I use 4 previous time steps. So instead of giving `input_shape=(4, 5)` of LSTM, what if I give `input_shape=(1, 20)`? Does it make a difference

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, changing the input from `batch_size, timesteps, input_dim` to `batch_size, 1, timesteps * input_dim` does make a difference.

Flattening the input array will lose the temporal relationship between your features.
In the case you have given, the temporal flow of information is:

```
a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4
b1 -> b2 -> b3 -> b4
c1 -> c2 -> c3 -> c4
d1 -> d2 -> d3 -> d4
e1 -> e2 -> e3 -> e4
```

Therefore, flattening the time dimension corresponds to an input of all timesteps `1-4` *at the same time*. This means the network is no longer acting in a recurrent manner and prevents generating an output sequence.